# iBeacon when app is just killed

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I have made iBeacon iOS app. Everything with iBeacon works perfectly except one thing. When I kill app from task manager and screen is still ON, iBeacon is not working.

But when I lock the screen and then turn on screen again(even without unlocking), it gets this needed refresh and iBeacon is seeing things again and sending me notifications.

Maybe someone has seen this issue before?

Comment: How long do you wait for a detection when the screen is on?

Comment: It could last forever if I dont make" -> screen off -> screen on" process. Normally when app is open or in background this process takes average 10 seconds.

Comment: @davidgyoung Is there way to receive notification about my state at position right after app is killed? Now I got notifications only after state changes (usually only exit position). 
I am trying to stop and start monitoring after app is killed to forces the notification, but doesn't seem it works